# How to write OR and AND combination in KQL query?

Tags: search, search-results, 2016, kql

I have to build `KQL` using combination of multiple `AND` and `OR`. I have following query:

```
((Property1:Value OR Property2:Value) AND (Property3:Value AND Property4:Value))
```

I have tried above query but it doesn't worked for me.

Can any one help me out in building query in proper syntax?

I am working with **SP2016 and Search**.

Any reference link apart from [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference) is welcomed.

Comment: It should be `Property:Value` instead of `Condition`.. other than that your query syntax seems fine.

Comment: Changed as per suggestion, I will try to make sure again and revert it back here :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is fine. You should also know that there is a difference in KQL between `=` and `:`. The equals sign is equality. SO if you are seeking a phrase it should be enclosed in quotes. `MyProperty="these words"` The colon is the contains operator. You can add a `*` for suffix wildcard matching. `MyProperty:words` or `MyProperty:word*` or `MyProperty:"these words"`.